# Как получить фотографию из папки?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

В общем, есть такая проблема. У меня папка в которой помещены фото. Мне нужно, чтобы бот смог открыть папку и отправить фотографии в чат.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по меткам, вы используете библиотеку `pyTelegramBotAPI`. Если нет, скажите, пожалуйста

Чтобы отправить фото, вы можете использовать метод [`send_photo`](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.send_photo) следующим образом:

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types

img = open("Путь/до/файла", 'rb')
bot.send_photo(chat_id, img, caption="Подпись")
```

Answer (score 0):

Установка библиотек

```
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
pip install Pillow
```

Python код:

```
import telebot
from PIL import Image

TOKEN = ""  # Токен бота
PATH_TO_PHOTO = "photos/test.jpg"  # Путь до файла

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN, parse_mode=None)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_handler(message):
    with Image.open(PATH_TO_PHOTO) as im:
        bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=im)
    
bot.infinity_polling()
```